# How to calculate PCB byte for apdu command

Tags: c++, apdu, mifare

I need simple example for calculate PCB bit for APDU command. For example I have command select aplet:

```
{ 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x06, 0x9A, 0xFC, 0xC3, 0x22, 0x88, 0x91 };
```

were byte is:

- CLA
- INS
- P1
- P2
- Len
- Aplet ID(6 byte)

How I can calculate PCB for its command?

I know that it byte must be '0x02', but how to calculate it dynamically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Books has the "Smart Card Handbook By Wolfgang Rankl, Wolfgang Effing". It has tables 9-5 through 9-7 which give the PCB format.